# ReactSelect two fields and i need to save values from them in array

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-select

I have the next task:

```
<Select
placeholder={'1'}
onChange={setFilter('bathrooms')}
value={getFilter('bathrooms')}
options={[
{ value: '1', label: '1'},
{ value: '2', label: '2'},
{ value: '3', label: '3'},
{ value: '4', label: '4'},
]}
searchable={false}
defaultValue={ [1 ,5] }
/>
```

So i have two such Filters,one for min values and other for max values,and also i have reducer :

`export const setFilter = (state, action) => ({
    ...state,
    filters: {
    ...state.filters,
    [action.payload.id]:  action.payload.value  || undefined,
    },
    });`

When I change one select, seconds changes too. And in-store I got filters: value,
and i need filters[0]:value(for min one) and filters[1]:value(for max one)
Thanks a lot, guys.